# Interpretation of priors in example

Tags: probability, prior, gamma-distribution, inverse-gamma-distribution

Suppose you have 3 variances $W_{1},W_{2},W_{3}$ that can be expressed as $W_{j}=q_{j}V$  with $j = 1,2,3$. According to one model, $W_{3}$ should be pronounced and $W_{1}$, $W_{2}$ should be small to avoid large fluctuations.  Furthermore, we assume that $V$ has a prior $\text{Ga}(1, 0.001)$ on $1/V$ to make it diffuse. Apparently, priors $q_{3} \sim  \text{Ga}(1, 0.001)$ and $q_{1},q_{2} \sim \text{E}(10)$ are good choices although I don't understand why. That is basically my question.

I think the distribution for $V$ refers to the inverse gamma distribution. Probably I'm wrong but this corresponds to a distribution $\text{Inv-Gamma}(1, 1/0.001)$. I believe this is the correct change of parameters because the transformation $g(V) = 1/V$ leads to the same shape parameters and the inverse scale parameter (derivation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution#Derivation_from_Gamma_distribution).) However, this gives an indeterminate mean and standard deviation. That is one problem.

The second problem is that $q_{1}$ and  $q_{2}$ have means and standard deviations equal to $0.1$ (assuming that $\text{E}(10)$ refers to a exponential distribution). However, according to previous knowledge of the model, $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ are supposed to be smaller than $q_{3}$, but since $q_{3}$ has mean $0.001$ and standard deviation $0.001$, the chosen priors have means that contradict that proposition. After calculating posterior distributions, $q_{1}, q_{2}$ are indeed smaller than $q_{3}$. So I was wondering whether my interpretation of the priors is incorrect or the priors were good enough to obtain acceptable posterior distributions.

By the way, this is a part of a small analysis described in Congdon's book [Applied-Bayesian-Hierarchical-Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584887206)

Comment: What do you mean by "gives an indeterminate mean and SD"? If you are concerned that your prior distributions have means and SDs, why is that? Concerning the second problem, doesn't Congdon consistently use *precision* to parameterize scales (see the bottom of p. 12, for instance)? Thus, a $\Gamma(1,0.001)$ should have a mean of $1000$, not $0.001$.

Comment: What I mean is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+gamma+distribution+alpha%3D1+beta%3D1%2F0.001) I'm not sure if Congdon uses precisions consistently, although that makes more sense. Do you have the same book available? I don't see something relevant in p.12. I'm reading from the 2010 edition. Even if that's correct, Inv-Gamma(1,0.001) still [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+gamma+distribution+alpha%3D1+beta%3D1%2F0.001) indeterminate means and standard deviations. Not sure why. The plot looks okay.

Comment: I followed your link to Amazon and looked within the book there. But, once again, what exactly is the problem with using a prior distribution that has an undefined mean?

Comment: In a model, I don't think there is a problem. But it seemed odd at first when I tried to reason about the choice of priors.

Comment: Actually, many people try to dodge the question of choosing appropriate priors by making sure the ones they use are "diffuse." An extremely diffuse (that is, spread-out) distribution for an unbounded variable often will not have a defined mean. From this point of view your situation is perfectly ordinary.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't view page 12 in Amazon. However, it looks identical to my book. Do you mean the section that says "Obtaining Full Conditional Densities"?

Comment: You can view that page through a search on "Gamma". At the bottom it says "Suppose the second stage prior is $\mu_i\sim\text{Ga}(\alpha,\beta)$, namely, $$p(\mu_i|\alpha,\beta)=\mu_i^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta\mu_i}\beta^\alpha/ \Gamma(\alpha), \ldots"$$ That pins down what the notation means.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That clarifies the choice of 1/V. Now I get what you mean. The definition of Gamma is described using a prior $\beta$ instead of $1/\theta$. I'm not sure if Congdon is being consistent because it uses a lot of sources, but I think that solves it. Last question: Why does the plot of Inv-Gamma look as if it had a well-defined mean?

Comment: I couldn't tell you how to determine, simply by looking at a plot of the distribution itself, whether a mean is well-defined. This is an issue of what happens in the limit at infinity, which cannot appear in the plot!

Comment: Understood. Thanks! If you want, add you comments in an answer so I can select it as correct.